# how to backup/restore the host key in ssh server

Tags: ssh

I have a ssh server, and some clients have login it via key login. So the host identity of server has been stored in the known_host of clients.

I want to reinstall the server, but I hope it never impact the experience of client. I'm wondering whether it's possible to backup the host identity of server, then restore it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- You can backup those keys from **/etc/ssh/ssh_host***
- You can also backup all in **/etc/ssh** directory so that you keep all config and keys.
- And to restore put your keys back in the same location **/etc/ssh**

[image]

Comment: for posterity- pay attention to the permissions. All the `/etc/ssh/*` files should be owned by root:root, with 644 permissions except for those that end in *key, which should be 600.

Comment: Afterwards, you probably need a `sudo service ssh restart`